# Parse: send push notification from own server

Tags: ios, coldfusion, parse-platform, push-notification

I have implemented the Push Notifications system with Parse.com
**Everything works.**

The problem is that I want to be able to deliver push notifications **not from Parse.co**m system but from my own server.

I have a web application and if user A sends a normal message to user B... if user B has a device it will receive a Push notification saying to him: "hey you have a new message!".

So I'm wondering if it is possible to send Push Notification using Parse.com from my server and not using the Parse system.

Is this possible? Anybody that can give me a hint where to start?

At server side I already have the ID where to send the push, I simply need to implement a method that will be called everytime a message in my application is sent and the recipent has a device!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are javascript APIs for sending push . I have did same task using javascript APIs . 
https://parse.com/docs/js/

But you have to implement server side in javascript

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading right, the point of parse it that it makes push notifications much easier. For example check out the docs on how to implement the Apple Push Notification:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

There is an old blog post by Ray Camden that will help you here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2010/09/13/Guest-Post-Apple-Push-Notifications-From-ColdFusion-in-Ten-Minutes-or-Less

Which references https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns which is a Java interface for the Apple Push Notification service

I hope this helps a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Before no. From [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/server/guide):

> Parse Server does not implement any push notification functionality.

Now

Push delivery and push adapters have landed in 2.0.8.

Comment: This is no longer correct information. The have now added push notifications to Parse-Server.